# How to finger print storage in ionic plugin?

Tags: php, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

How to finger print storage in ionic plugin using php with mysql and how to authenticate during login.

ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-android-fingerprint-auth - This plugin is only used to authenticate the mobile's own fingerprint.

I need to build the ionic app for employee attendance. Is there any plugin to take the fingerprint registration and authenticate?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible. The fingerprint scanner only check if the fingerprint is on the device itself. So if you have multiple users on 1 device, it will never work. If anyone find the plugin, please share me..

Comment: Please add under comments section but not as part of answer.